# Need assistance with making a AHK Text spam script

Tags: windows, windows-10, script, autohotkey

I hope your all doing well! I'm a gamer with little to no knowledge about scripting, in a game I'm trying to make an auto hotkey script that will press the slash key first and then copy-paste the following text ''explode all''[I'm not sure 100% about this but it will somehow type this text or paste it through crtl+v] and then it will press enter and repeat every 30 milliseconds. I've tried making this through this article but this is pretty close to what I'm trying to do. https://www.howtogeek.com/97998/how-to-make-your-computer-press-a-key-every-x-seconds/, In a nutshell, I need to make a script that will press the following keys on my keyboard including the slash and enter button and repeat continuously every 30 milliseconds, also will need to know how to switch this on and off. Please make me this / guide me on how to make it.

Answer (score 0):

The following script might get you started (as I have not tested it).
The script starts and ends sending with the <kbd>F12</kbd> key.
If the target program is too slow to accept its input, you might need
to add some [Sleep](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Sleep.htm)
commands, for example between the `/` and the rest.

```
working = 0
SetKeyDelay, 10

F12::
If (working = 0) {
   working = 1
   SetTimer, SendString, 30
} else {
   working = 0
   SetTimer, SendString, Off
}   
return

SendString:
Send, /explode all{Enter}
Return
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your script but it gave me a error message, <https://gyazo.com/4f9fa9ab6c94b0cfbae5eda474a05129>
Please tell me how I can fix it.
To make it clear I wanna make a script that does the following
/
explode all
[Enter Key]
That's what I'm trying to do here. Please tell me what should I do. I did not understand your meaning but putting a sleep command even after spending time on the AHK trying to understand.

Comment: I said it was untested - missing parenthesis. Fixed. It will help learning about AHK, to find what does a "command" just google for "AutoHotkey command".

Comment: Hi. I tried this script of yours and even did google it AHK Command. I did not understand it. In the game I'm trying to use this script in which I paste it into the chat requires that I press the Slash key before being able to use the chat [Just wanted to say that to clarify anything] The script is too fast for the game to register the keystrokes. How can I overcome this? P.S: I want to thank you for helping me

Comment: I already remarked on it in my answer. I added a small delay in the answer.

Comment: Hi! I want to thank you again for helping me, the script is almost perfected, the only problem is that it's not doing it's too fast still to register it, it works half the time, when it doesn't it says, something like explode al or explode all /, that's how it's showing up. What can I do to fix this problem? So yes It works but only half the time.

Comment: Try the [SetKeyDelay command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm) as above. Enlarge the 10 milliseconds delay if it's not enough, or add the second parameter to the command (read the documentation).

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (tick the V sign) and/or upvote (up-arrow).

Comment: Hey. The script has a new problem, I tried adjusting the time but it simply won't work. I'm getting this problem where the slash key seems to be getting pressed twice. for it's showing as /explode all in the chat, (The Slash key is pressed to open the chat box. What should I do? I increased the SetKeyDelay command and yes I took a look at it's page. P.S: I think you should re-add the sleep command as it's no longer but do as you think as you know more AHK.

Comment: At the limit you could add a Sleep command after every character, if the SetKeyDelay command is not helpful. Feel free to change the script. In cases such as this, one must try and try again until it works.