# Need some guidance about AHK Text Loop Script

Tags: windows, script, autohotkey

I'm a gamer and mainly play Roblox, I need to set up a script that will open the chatbox by pressing the slash key and then it will say explode all and then the enter key. I've already managed to come up with a  script, I also read that you will need to have a delay between each keystroke for it to register for some reason, I can't seem to figure out how to do that. Any guidance will be appreciated highly.
Here's the script I've made so far

```
working = 0

F12::
If (working = 0) {
   working = 1
   SetTimer, SendString, 30
} else {
   working = 0
   SetTimer, SendString, Off
}   
return

SendString:
Send, /
Sleep, 10  ; 10 milliseconds
Send, unchar all{Enter}
Return
```

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1547952/need-assistance-with-making-a-ahk-text-spam-script

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, many games may need extended time between keystrokes. 10 milliseconds may simply not be enough. You may wish to try increasing this to 20 milliseconds minimum.

Regarding options for sending individual key strokes with delays, try replacing ex.:

```
SendString:
Send, /
Sleep, 10  ; 10 milliseconds
Send, unchar all{Enter}
Return
```

with:

```
SendString:
Send, /
Sleep, 20  ; 20 milliseconds
Send, u
Sleep, 20  ; 20 milliseconds
Send, n
Sleep, 20  ; 20 milliseconds
Send, c
Sleep, 20  ; 20 milliseconds
Send, h
Sleep, 20  ; 20 milliseconds
Send, a
Sleep, 20  ; 20 milliseconds
Send, r
Sleep, 20  ; 20 milliseconds
Send, {Space} 
Sleep, 20  ; 20 milliseconds
Send, a
Sleep, 20  ; 20 milliseconds
Send, l
Sleep, 20  ; 20 milliseconds
Send, l
Sleep, 20  ; 20 milliseconds
Send, {Enter}
Sleep, 20  ; 20 milliseconds
Return
```